# AWS Sentiment Analysis tutorial crash "No module named nltk"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr, sentiment-analysis

Trying to play with sentiment analysis hosted in AWS i am following the tutorial

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/emr/getting-started-emr-sentiment-streaming-job.html

In step 5 it describes how to create a EMR cluster to consume mapper and process data stores in S3.

However i get problems since

```
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
/usr/bin/python: No module named nltk
```

When bootstrap action is launched and executes the specified sh file:

s3://awsdocs/gettingstarted/latest/sentiment/config-nltk.sh

Does anyone has any hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like its a known issue on the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=588369#588369).  Looks like an issue between pip version and the version of python installed. The steps to fix are on the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=588369#588369) but it looks like it is as simple as downloading the bootstrap action and  tweaking some symlinks.